# Merge 2 json files with python adding new "key":"value"

Tags: python, json

Have 2 JSON files:
First file is:

```
{
  "Bob": {
    "tags": ["theme1", "theme2", "theme3"
    ]},
  "John": {
    "tags": ["theme2", "theme3"
    ]}
}
```

and second file is:

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2": {
            "level3": {
                "Bob": {
                    "gear": "Yes"
                },
                "John": {
                    "gear": "None"
                },
                "Marcel": {
                    "gear": "N/A"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to merge both in a third one like:

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2": {
            "level3": {
                "Bob": {
                    "gear": "Yes",
                    "tags": ["theme1", "theme2", "theme3"]
                    
                },
                "John": {
                    "gear": "None",
                    "tags": ["theme2", "theme3"]
                },
                "Marcel": {
                    "gear": "N/A",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Deeper level of second file cause me troubles. Output file needs to be a valid JSON.
Thanks for any advice.

I tried this:

```
# Read data from the first JSON file
with open('file1.json', 'r') as f1:
    data1 = json.load(f1)

# Read data from the second JSON file
with open('file2.json', 'r') as f2:
    data2 = json.load(f2)

# Merge the data based on common keys
merged_data = {}

for key in data1:
    #print(key)
    for level1 in data2:
        #print(level1)
        if key != level1:
            for level2 in data2[level1]:
                #print(level2)
                if key != level2:
                    for level3 in data2[level1][level2]:
                        #print(level3)
                        if key != level3:
                            for level4 in data2[level1][level2][level3]:
                                #print(level4)
                                if key == level4:
                                    merged_data[key] = {"gear": data1[key]["gear"], **data2[level1][level2][level3][key]}




merged_data = f"{data2} + {merged_data} }}}}}}"

merged_data = json.dumps(merged_data.read_vms_tags())

with open('merged_json.json', 'w') as merged_file:
    json.dump(merged_data, merged_file, indent=4)
```

The best I could get was having merged file with same level.

Chris, thanks advice to edit my post :)

Comment: You're having trouble. Okay. What have you tried thus far?

Comment: For each key in the first file, lookup `secondfile['level1']['level2']['level3'][key]`. Use `.update()` to merge the dictionaries.

Comment: Why is deeper level causing trouble? Accessing all levels is the same.

Comment: If you want to show code, edit your question to insert it. Comments do not offer the requisite formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach: At each level, update the value. Then recursively traverse into the value's values and update them as well.

```py
import json


def update(new_data, target):
    for key, value in target.items():
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            continue

        # Update the value
        updated_value = new_data.get(key, {})
        value.update(updated_value)

        # Since value is a dictionary, update its values recursively
        update(new_data, value)


# This is the new data
with open("file1.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    data1 = json.load(stream)

# This is the data to be updated
with open("file2.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    data2 = json.load(stream)

# Update
update(data1, data2)
with open("merged_json.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    json.dump(data2, stream, indent=4)
```

#### Notes

- The statement `updated_value = new_data.get(key, {})` gets the updated value. If the key is not found in `new_data`, we got ourselves an empty dictionary.
- The next step is to update the value using `updated_value`. If `updated_value` is an empty dictionary, nothing will get updated.
- The important part of the update function is when value is a dictionary, we call update on that value in order to recursively update that value's values.
- This function works regardless of how many levels the the user's data is in.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

# Load the first JSON file
with open('file1.json', 'r') as f:
    file1 = json.load(f)

# Load the second JSON file
with open('file2.json', 'r') as f:
    file2 = json.load(f)

# Merge the two JSON files
for name, data in file1.items():
    if name in file2['level1']['level2']['level3']:
        file2['level1']['level2']['level3'][name].update(data)

# Save the merged JSON to a new file
with open('merged_file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(file2, f, indent=4)
```

This code loads the **two JSON files**, merges them by **updating the data** for each name in the **second file** with the data from the **first file**, and then saves the merged data to **a third JSON file**.

Comment: Hi Razzer, 1st will be constant, but 2nd will contain different levels, depending on the backed server that have to apply 3rd file, that is why I will try to iterate up to 7 level at the end. Thanks for help.

Comment: Forgot to mention that PATH to let say "user" has different names.